# Android Studio Showing Unknown Symbols in editor and autocompletion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, editor

Suddenly Android studio displaying different characters for some symbols and Gibberish name in autocomplete. Is happening in both kotlin only and java only projects. when I select the autocompletion option it selected properly I mean it shows the correct method name in the editor, when I copy the symbol and paste it elsewhere it pastes as a normal character, also the app is successfully building and executing and the source code in notepad looks fine.  How to fix it?

[[image: Gibberish Characters in AutoCompletion]
[[image: Symblos replacement]

Comment: I recently saw something like that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62707758). It seems they fixed it by changing the font.

Comment: @MikeM. tried changing different fonts many times already. did not solve.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got. I've never seen that outside of these two questions.

Comment: Does that happens with other projects?

Comment: @MikeM. i have changed font from settings many times tried restoring it defaults too but in editor it is not taking effect . Font changing isn't working I guess in android studio. Any other way to change it forcefully?

Comment: @Padia yes , in all projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions after invalidating the cache and restarting many times, changing android studio font, editor font numerous times. finally, I was able to solve this problem you just need to change the color scheme font.

Thanx @MikeM. for referring the similar post.

[image]